# How to find the numeric code(s) corresponding to arbitrary key?

Tags: keyboard

How can I find out the numeric code(s) that my keyboard sends when I press some arbitrary key, or key chord, such as Ctrl-', or ⌘-5?

Answer (score 1):

If you work on Windows, you should maybe go on this website :

[Alt Codes](http://www.alt-codes.net/)

It provides all the symbols you'll be able to make with your Ctrl or Alt or whatever prefix you want to use.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed description of the linked content, and explain how it relates to the question? This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page goes offline. In addition, please be careful posting links in answers of this nature—they could be seen by the community as spam, correctly or otherwise. See the [help/behavior] for more information.